# Java: How to print the reference of an Integer Object?

Tags: java, reference, integer

Suppose

```
Integer integerA = 500;
```

I would like to print the reference returned.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this is a case of the [XY-Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  Why do you need this?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Enthusiatic, See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the reference to the object as a number you can use Unsafe on JVMs which support it.  You can place the reference in an array and access it with Unsafe.getInt() for 32-bit references (Note: most 64-bit JVMs will be using 32-bit references) or Unsafe.getLong()  This will access the reference as a number, but it could change as soon as you get it if a GC occures and the object is moved.

Another complication is that CompressedOops means the index to the object can be translated a number of different ways.  To keep things simple, I suggest using a heap of 4 GB to 26GB.  For these sizes, you shift the address by `<< 3` to get the address.

BTW You can use Unsafe.putInt(x, 1, hashCode) to overwrite the system hashCode. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can get to displaying a reference is the hash code as it would be calculated by Object, System.IdentityHashCode(). Integer, of course, overrides hashCode so the Integer's own hashCode() method is definitely not related to its reference.

There is, in fact, no guarantee that System.IdentityHashCode has anything to do with the reference - it is just a number that is always the same when calculated for the same object, and that is, as far as possible, different for different objects.

Answer (score 2):

People keep answering about `hashCode()`, but `hashCode()` for an `Integer` is the value of the `Integer`, it has nothing to do with its location in memory.  Additionally, in general, just because two `Objects` have the same `hashCode()` does **not** mean that they reference the same `Object`.

**EDIT (in response to comment)**:
Even if you use [IdentityHashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29), which gives the non-overrided version of `hashCode()`, you still won't get a memory address.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic I removed it.

Comment: so ,how to get the memory address of an Integer ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you *can* get the actual memory location of an object in Java (for printing purposes or otherwise). Even when you do `System.out.println(new Object())`, what you see *isn't* a "reference" location, it's a string containing the object's hash code.

Comment: Apparently you can, see [Peter Lawrey's response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820164/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-reference-address).

Comment: @SteveP.: You can't with *defined* Java. You can **on Oracle's JVM** using undocumented internals. So not on (as a comment on that answer mentions) J9, JRockit, Dalvik, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That prints the overloaded version of "toString" method in Integer class. 
In general, if a class didn't overload that method, it prints the classname + hashcode. Something like this (you have to do by hand):

```
integerA.getClass().getName() + "@" + integerA.hashCode()
```

Comment: Which prints the class name and hashcode, not the "reference."

Answer (score 0):

The default `toString` method of various classes involves the result of the `hashCode` method. Perhaps you're looking for that, as it's the closest I can think of to "printing the reference".

Answer (score -1):

The default implementation(had it not been overridden) would print the object as something like

```
Integer i = 95;
System.out.println(i.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(i.hashCode()));
//java.lang.Integer@5f
```

In case of an integer, the `hashCode` value is the same as the underlying value.