# Memory address of a list in scala

Tags: scala

When I try to print custom object in scala it gives its memory address

```
object Test; println(Test)<br/>
Output : Test$@250f9a46
```

when It comes to list it prints string as toString been overridden

```
println(List(1,2,3))<br/>
output : List(1, 2, 3)
```

Is there a way to get the address?

Comment: This is more JVM question than just Scala one. This question shows how to achieve that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820164/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-reference-address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a reference address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820164/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-reference-address)

Answer (score 4):

It's actually not the memory address you're getting by the default toString method but the hashcode of the Object. (The memory address might also change during runtime because the garbage collector moves the object between different generation space.)

The toString implementation in java.lang.Object is

```
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

So you could use this code to get a similar result.