# Store the location of an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers

I want to be able to store a reference to an array, but not really sure if pointers are necessary or where to start. I'm looking for functionality similar to using ref with a function, but in a variable.

Comment: do you mean `two-dimensional-array` or `hash-table` ?

Comment: Do you mean you want two or more variables to point to the same array?

Comment: I mean that I have an array somewhere and I need to be able to access it on the fly. Its outside the scope of where I need to access it, and I dont want to copy it. Im hoping that it is possible to just store a reference to that array so I can access it through that.

Comment: Not very OOP. I think you shouldn't think about the data itself but about the functionality that is built using that data and provide a class (also a static class) that provide the required functionality based on the data stored in that array

Comment: Well if you assign it to another variable (eg var tempArray=MyArray) and pass tempArry around as an argument, it will 'point' to the array. I believe array is a reference type so tempArry and MyArray are effectively pointers anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have an array:

```
int[] a = new int[42];
```

The variable `a` is a reference to the array. You can make another one like this:

```
int[] b = a;
```

Now `a` and `b` refer to the same array.

You can assign a value to an element like this:

```
a[0] = 666;
```

And then see that same value using the other reference:

```
Debug.Assert(b[0] == 666);
```

---

What this boils down to is the fact that arrays are [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx). So the assignment operator copies the reference to the object, and does not copy the object itself. Contrast this with [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), e.g. structs, for which the assignment operator copies the value of the object.

Comment: I dident think it worked like that. Had been assuming b=a would just make a copy of all the data in a into b. Will try now, thanks!

Comment: @Zshelley Arrays are reference types.. therefore the reference is copied.. not the data they reference.

Comment: A copy is only made for a value type. Reference type variables (all objects) are pointers to objects on the heap - in C# they just don't look like pointers. In David's example, a and b are pointers. However, int a = 1; int b = a; ( int is a value type) defines two variables with separate copies of the value 1. You need to understand clearly the difference between value and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer (a reference to a memory location), in a high level language such as C#, is not necessary, if you want to store the reference to an array, because they're reference types. All reference type variables work like pointers, but the process of referencing to a memory location, in high level languages such as C#, is totally automatic and it is hidden to the user.

I have answered a question about pointers (in Java) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118657/is-there-a-concept-of-pointers-or-unsafe-code-in-java/7118920#7118920). Even if the language is different, Java is a high level language like C# and the process of referencing to a memory location is similar.

About your question, if you have an array like this:

```
int[] myArray = new int[2];
```

you can store its reference in another array like this:

```
int[] myStoredArrayRef = myArray;
```

Now, the two objects are referring to the same array, because they're referring to the same 'location' in memory (you copied its reference). Indeed, if you modify an element of `myArray` in this way:

```
myArray[0] = 123;
```

also the element of `myStoredArrayRef` will change:

```
Console.WriteLine(myStoredArrayRef[0]); //it will print '123';
```

You're able also to store a reference to a List, because they're [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) (as rightly pointed out by @DavidHeffernan) like the arrays, with the same procedure.

Comment: Yes it would because they are also reference types.

Comment: @Zshelley Yes! David has disclosed me :-)

Comment: I would phrase it differently: All reference type variables are actually pointers without you noticing it in C#.

Comment: I wouldn't rephrase it. References provide much more than pointers do.